# How to profile a Django custom management command exclusively

Tags: python, django, profiling

I would like to profile a custom management command that is relatively CPU intensive (renders an image using PIL). When I use the following command I get all sorts of Django modules (admin, ORM etc) in my profiling results:

```
python -m cProfile manage.py testrender
```

I have removed all imports that can potentially import Django but I am guessing the following is the culprit:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
```

Is there a way to filter out `cProfile` results? (only filenames are shown, no paths) Or, is there any other way to exclude/include respective modules/packages from profiling?

Comment: @Geo grep doesn't help much since file paths are not given. Only filenames are printed out. Now suppose I have utils.py that I want to profile and there's another utils.py somewhere in Django.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved this problem the following way:

```
from cProfile import Profile
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    ...

    def _handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Actual code I want to profile
        pass

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if options['profile']:
            profiler = Profile()
            profiler.runcall(self._handle, *args, **options)
            profiler.print_stats()
        else:
            self._handle(*args, **options)
```

This way profiling statistics are gathered within the scope of `_handle`. So instead of:

```
python -m cProfile manage.py testrender
```

I'll have to run:

```
python manage.py testrender --profile
```

which is even better.

Comment: Seems like this is no longer valid with the changes in Django, but I figured it out from this. [Here's an updated example](https://gist.github.com/4236077).

Answer (score 1):

Separate the PIL functionality into its own function/class in its own module, and import it from your management command. Then you can test/profile the PIL functionality independently of Django.

Comment: It is just like you said, in a seperate module and being imported from the command. The problem is how to profile independently. I don't even need super isolation, I just don't want 50 related entries and 950 unrelated ones. Would you like me to post some code?

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. If you have it separated out into its own module (which has no references to Django at all), can't you write a simple test harness to exercise that module, and profile that? I can't see how there would be any Django code in your profile output then.

Comment: Creating another executable you mean? That would be a solution. I am just trying to find out if it would be possible somehow, using a Django management command.

Answer (score 0):

If I can't find any answers. [Gprof2Dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843671/profiling-in-python-who-called-the-function/843725#843725) can be an acceptable hack.

It doesn't filter out modules I'm not interested, but hopefully it will make it easier to inspect the results visually seperating my code and Django modules.